# How do I stop my for loop after it iterates through an array and finds the matching element?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, user-input

I have a for loop that iterates through an array of type struct but when I pass the user input to the function that retrieves the value, it prints out 10 times. I need my main() to ask the user which # of the address book to print so then it is passed to the function that prints it out but the function checks if there is a such number in the array and if there is then it prints out the values of that inputted #. 
Here is the code that keeps printing the printAddress() ten times:

```
STRUCTURE FOR 
struct addressBook
{ 
int entryNum;
char name[100];
char address[100];
}; 

void printAddress(struct addressBook addresses, int num)
{ 
    int n = 0;
    for(n=0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        if (addresses.checkNum == num)
        { 
            printf("\nBELOW IS ADDRESS # %i DETAILS: \n", num);
            printf("Address Book Number: %i \n", addresses.entryNum);
            printf("Name: %s", addresses.name);
            printf("Address: %s \n", addresses.address);

    }
    }

}


my main function: 

int main()
{ 
// create a addressBook array of at least 10 
struct addressBook addresses[10];

//if statements where user can select to 
//add a name to address book, display a single name or quit the program

//this is if they choose to display a single name using a number 
else if (choice == 2)
    {
    int num; 
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter book number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printAddress(addresses[i], num);
    } 

return 0 
}
```

Comment: Add a `break;` at the end of the `if() { ...} ` block. (also you have to pass (a pointer to) the whole array, instead of a single item)

Comment: Add either a `break` or a `return` after printing the information.  Which is better depends on whether there's any code to execute after the loop.  If you return, it is easy to print a 'not found' message aftrer the loop.  If you break, you have to know whether you found the match or not.  Please fix typos before asking your question on SO (`adresses` should be `addresses`).  And note that your function is given a single address, yet you loop, without indexing an array – you need to rethink that code.

Comment: The posted code, when run through the compiler, results in several error and warning messages.  When compiling, always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: in function: `printAddress()`,   starting with the statement: `if (adresses.checkNum == num)` and including all statements in the `if` code block, replace `adresses` (and `addresses`) with `addresses[n]`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, im having a hard time understanding how to index the array since its being passed from the main to the function. Is my main sending the wrong data or are my arguments wrong for the function?

Comment: As written, your function arguments are wrong, and then your call conforms to the current arguments, but isn't correct when you revise them.  Making the minimum changes, you need something like: `void printAddress(struct addressBook *addresses, int num)` for the function definition, and you then call it with `printAddress(addresses, num);`. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ It is easy to argue that you should use one of: `void printAddress(int n_addr, struct addressBook *addresses, int num)` or `void printAddress(int n_addr, struct addressBook addresses[n_addr], int num)` to pass the number of addresses to the function as well, instead of hard-coding 10.  The latter uses VLA (variable-length array) notation — a feature of C99 and (nominally) an optional feature of C11 or C17.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im not allowed to use pointers yet so would I be using 
void printAddress(int n_addr, struct addressBook addresses[n_addr], int num) and it will do the same thing?

Comment: Asinine rules!  You can't avoid using pointers if you have functions and arrays!  Yes, it is effectively the same.  You'll need to modify the code inside the function to index into the array, regardless of which notation you use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I am getting and error after I changed it. I get argument: type "struct address" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct address *"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation of your code that seems to work as I'd expect it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct addressBook
{
    int entryNum;
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
};

static
void printAddress(int n_addr, struct addressBook addresses[n_addr], int num)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < n_addr; n++)
    {
        if (addresses[n].entryNum == num)
        {
            printf("\nBELOW IS ADDRESS # %i DETAILS:\n", num);
            printf("Address Book Number: %i\n", addresses[n].entryNum);
            printf("Name: %s\n", addresses[n].name);
            printf("Address: %s\n", addresses[n].address);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct addressBook addresses[10] =
    {
        { 1, "John Doe", "1234 Any St, Some Town, CA 94301" },
        { 2, "Mary Fog", "1270 Some St, Any Town, CA 94303" },
        { 3, "Anne Pit", "1240 Any Rd, Some City, CA 94301" },
        { 4, "Bill Zoo", "1252 Some St, Any Town, CA 94303" },
        { 5, "Phil Tin", "1258 Any Rd, Some City, CA 94301" },
    };

    int num;
    printf("Entry number? ");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printAddress(5, addresses, num);

    return 0;
}
```

You could add a `return;` or `break;` after the printing in the body of the `if` in the function.  If you add `return;`, you can add a 'printf("Entry %d not found\n", num);` after the loop and before the function returns.

Note that you don't normally want blanks before newlines; trailing blanks are sloppy.  Also, there's a newline after the name now; it looks ugly if you run the name into the tag `Address:`.

Given the program `addr83` compiled from `addr83.c`, an example run is:

```
$ addr83
Entry number? 4

BELOW IS ADDRESS # 4 DETAILS:
Address Book Number: 4
Name: Bill Zoo
Address: 1252 Some St, Any Town, CA 94303
$
```

Comment: I am still getting an error. I believe its because I am not passing the array correctly. This program I shared on here is not my assignment but similar to it. I would really like to share my whole program but I am afraid someone will steal it.

Comment: You should only need to name the array in the function call, as my example shows.  If you have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) for your “real” program, you may send it to me by email — see my profile. Include a link to this question so I know what it is about.